# How to encrypt generated RSA private key and decrypt in c#

Tags: c#, cryptography

I have seen articles regarding encrypt/decrypt data using Private/Public key. All I want to do is to just encrypt a generated RSA private key already stored in a file. I have been browsing widely to get an idea how it can be done but with no luck.I presume my question is rather an unusual one. Please help!

Comment: Are you sure you want to be encrypting a private key?  What are you using to encrypt it - another public/private key?  This feels like it might be an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @James. I've developed a light control application.To deploy application  for  first time at client side, I'll be sending private RSA key in encrypted format, with  encrypted pass phrase to client through email for validation. When client  enters passphrase for the initial set up ,if that password matches ,  aplication decrypts the encrypted file and make connection with  server to control lights. Initially, thought DPAPI  fulfill my requirements but  encryption and decryption process  solely dependent on current user. So I am looking for Cryptographic algorithm to encrypt RSA key.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a *Key derivation function, to turn your password into a symmetric key which you can use to encrypt your private key. If you solely use the .NET framework, you should use the [Rfc2898DeriveBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes?view=netframework-4.7) class for that. If you are able to use BouncyCastle, then [SCrypt](https://bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/crypto/generators/SCrypt.html) would be preferred.

Then you can encrypt your key, prefreably using the [AES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aescryptoserviceprovider?view=netframework-4.7) algorithm.

Some usable code sample can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10366194/1039462)